# Jenkins build flow plugin complete prematurely after executing the first parallel jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-build-flow

I've got the Jenkins build flow below:

```
parallel (
  { build("a1") },
  { build("a2") },
  { build("a3") },
  { build("a4") },
  { build("a5") },
  { build("a6") },
  { build("a7") },
  { build("a8") }
);
parallel (
  { build("p1") },
  { build("p2") },
  { build("p3") },
  { build("p4") },
  { build("p5") }
);
parallel (
  { build("p6") },
  { build("p7") },
  { build("p8") },
  { build("p9") },
  { build("p0") }
);
build("q1");
build("q2");
build("q23");
build("q3");
build("q4");
build("q5");
build("q6");
build("q7");
build("q8");
build("q9");
parallel (
  { build("q0") },
  { build("t1") },
  { build("t2") },
  { build("t3") },
  { build("t4") },
  { build("t5") }
);
build("t6");
build("t7");
build("t8");
build("t9");
```

All of job's config are standard, I'm running Jenkins ver. 1.646 (I just upgraded it) and CloudBees Build Flow plugin 0.18(also just upgraded as I'm traying to fix this issue).

My problem is, after executing successfully the first group of parallel jobs, Jenkins marks this job as success and finishes without executing the other parallel groups or jobs.

My jobs are a mixtures of several technologies - compiled and packaged python, java maven projects, sbt scala projects, unit tests, coverage tests, docker builds and pushes to a docker registry.

All of the jobs work individually, If I comment the first parallel, it runs the next one and stops after the last job in that parallel group is complete too.

Answer (score 0):

After tweaking with this for a while, I notice that Jenkins would not continue building is one of the jobs is unstable. I just fixed the unstable job and the build flow plugin started to work like a charm.